# How to ssh into a server in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build React Image') {
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
        stage('Push React Image') {
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
        stage('Build Backend Image') {
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
        stage('Push Backend Image') {
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
        def remote = [:]
        remote.name = '...'
        remote.host = '...'
        remote.user = '...'
        remote.password = '...'
        remote.allowAnyHosts = true
        stage('SSH into the server') {
            steps {
                writeFile file: 'abc.sh', text: 'ls -lrt'
                sshPut remote: remote, from: 'abc.sh', into: '.'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I followed the documentation on this page: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/ to ssh into the server in a Jenkinsfile. My final goal is to ssh into the server, pull from dockerhub, build, and put it up.

First, I just want to successfully ssh into it.

This Jenkinsfile gives me `WorkflowScript: 61: Expected a stage @ line 61, column 9. def remote = [:]`

Not sure if this the right way to do it. If there is a simpler way to ssh into a server and just perform commands as I do it manually, that would also be great to know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this and the example is still not fixed.

Comment: It's 2023, and it's still the same.  Glad to find this question.

Answer (score 5):

The error arises from the statement `def remote = [:]` and subsequent assignments being outside the `stage` block. In addition, since the declarative syntax does not support statements directly within the `steps` block, you also need to wrap that part of the code within a `script` block.

```
stage('SSH into the server') {
    steps {
        script {
            def remote = [:]
            remote.name = '...'
            remote.host = '...'
            remote.user = '...'
            remote.password = '...'
            remote.allowAnyHosts = true
            writeFile file: 'abc.sh', text: 'ls -lrt'
            sshPut remote: remote, from: 'abc.sh', into: '.'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Been kicking myself over why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not related to the plugin but to the declarative syntax of the pipeline. As the error message states a stage was expected and it found the variable declaration.

Pipelines need to contain stages, stages must contain a stage. a stage must then have a step.... In the past I have wasted many days trying to comply with the strict declarative syntax but now avoid it at all cost.

Try the simplified scripted pipeline below.

```
stage('Build React Image') {
    echo "stage1"
}
stage('Push React Image') {
    echo "stage2"
}
stage('Build Backend Image') {
    echo "stage3"
}
stage('Push Backend Image') {
     echo "stage4"
}
def remote = [:]
remote.name = '...'
remote.host = '...'
remote.user = '...'
remote.password = '...'
remote.allowAnyHosts = true
stage('SSH into the server') {
    writeFile file: 'abc.sh', text: 'ls -lrt'
    sshPut remote: remote, from: 'abc.sh', into: '.'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ssh` command can be used inside a regular [shell script](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script)

Example:

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {

        stage('Deploy') {
            options {
                /* do not pull the repository */
                skipDefaultCheckout()
            }
            environment {
                /* server IP */
                SERVER_IP = '8.8.8.8'
            }
            steps {
                sh '''
                    ssh $SERVER_IP "
                        echo Hello
                    "
                '''
            }
        } /* stage('Deploy') */

    }
}
```